# advertisement banner show only once in browser session

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, local-storage, sessionstorage

How do you show an advertisement banner only once during a browser session using JavaScript or jQuery in a website? Once the session is closed and the browser is closed, the ad must be shown again when I open the website in the browser again. One more thing when i navigate across website banner must display unless it is not closed.

Comment: You should have a look at [window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) event it is not exactly the behaviour you are expecting

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/global-variable-usage-on-page-reload/

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`sessionStorage`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

> The `sessionStorage` property allows you to access a `session Storage object`. sessionStorage is similar to `Window.localStorage`, the only difference is while data stored in `localStorage` has *no expiration set*, data stored in `sessionStorage` gets **cleared when the page session ends**. A page session lasts for **as long as the browser is open** and survives over page reloads and restores.

*Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated, which differs from how session cookies work.*

```js
var banner = document.getElementById('banner');
if (sessionStorage.getItem('set') === 'set') {
  banner.style.display = 'none';
} else {
  sessionStorage.setItem('set', 'set');
}
```

```css
#banner {
  width: 320;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">Banner</div>
```

### [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/ogghtw9L/1/)

Comment: How to expire localstorage on browser exit so that when i close browser and restart it, banner must show again.. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @user6543514 Ooh.. I misread your question... Use sessionStorage instead..

Comment: Ok i have tried that too but when i right click and tries to open it in new tab sessonstorage doesn't work @Rayon. So can i use both localstorage and sessionstorage to achieve desired results ?? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use cookie to remember if ad was displayed or not.

You can use this plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Make a method to display the ad:

```
showAd() {
 // cookie not set, display the ad and set the cookie
 if($.cookie('adDisplayed') === 'undefined') {
   // code to display the add
   // .....
   // set cookie
   $.cookie('adDisplayed', '1', { expires: 7 }); // set the cookie

 }
}
```

To destroy the cookie when user leaves the page, bind beforeunload event

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function() { 
    $.removeCookie('adDisplayed'); 
})
```

Comment: Thanks Razvan Moldovan. But i want to destroy cookie if user leaves my website or close browser by jquery or javascript. Show practical example to help it is really appreciated..

Comment: Ok i will check into it.. Thanks a Lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a cookie with JavaScript to remember the visit.

**Example**

```
<div id="banner"></div>
<script>
  if(typeof $.cookie("banner") === 'undefined' || $.cookie("banner") != "1") {
      $("#banner").html("My Banner");
      $.cookie("banner", "1");
  }
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
      $.removeCookie("banner");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Plz show me some example to achieve it.. @FabioWidmer

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I will look into it.. thnx again.

Comment: Note that this script needs jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with **fadeIn()** and **fadeOut()** methods explained [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp)

like this :

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    $("#banner").fadeOut();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bc8jgoga/

Comment: Sry its not what i am looking for.. Actually banner must not display as i navigate through a website.